# How to get the Oracle sql Id in the application

Tags: sql, .net, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a .net web service that makes some dynamically generated sql calls against ORACLE and they are performing bad in production. The DBAs keep asking for the sql ids to tune the query. They can use the OEM tool to find the slow performing query and get the sql id. But I was wondering if there is a way to know the sql id and log it so that I can retrieve it and give it to the DBAs for tuning.
Is this something that can be achieved in .net ?

Answer (score 1):

Query the V$SQL dynamic view to get the SQL ID;

More on the V$SQL:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2113.htm#REFRN30246

Answer (score 1):

The following package dbms_application_info is very useful to instrument your queries.

Prior to running the processing logic from app layer, set the module/action, to identify your module.

```
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.set_module(module_name => 'add_order',
                                 action_name => 'processing orders');
```

After that, set the client_info with a marker that indicates what processing is going on prior to running the sql.

Eg:

```
exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('starting load from staging');

--Run the query 
insert into dest_table select * from staging;

update dest_table set last_updated=sysdate;

exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('updated the last_updated column');

delete from dest_table where order_value<0;

exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('deleted -ve orders');
```

When this happens we can have a look at v$session/v$sql to see where the processing is currently taking place

```
SELECT sid,
       serial#,
       username,
       osuser,
       module,
       action,
       client_info
FROM   v$session
WHERE module='add_order'

SELECT *
FROM   v$sql
WHERE module='add_order'
```

have a look at the link
https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dbms_application_info

Answer (score 0):

If the application can capture sufficient information to identify the session in [v$session](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SESSION.html), you can query it from another session to grab the value of `sql_id`, or else query the [v$sql_monitor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SQL_MONITOR.html) view if you are licensed (requires Enterprise Edition and the Diagnostics and Tuning option). Use [dbms_application_info](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/dbms_application_info) to tag activity for better tracking.

Also you can configure database services if you haven't already, so that applications connect to a specific service rather than a generic one, and this will appear in v$session.service_name and be reported in OEM etc.

If it's practical to capture the session details from the same session immediately after the poorly-performing SQL statement completes (which it may not be, if the connection times out for example), you might try querying the `prev_` details from v$session:

```
select s.prev_sql_id
     , s.prev_child_number
     , s.prev_exec_start
     , s.prev_exec_id
     , p.sql_text as prev_sql
     , p.plan_hash_value as prev_plan
from   v$session s
       left join v$sql p on p.sql_id = s.prev_sql_id and p.child_number = s.prev_child_number
where  s.audsid = sys_context('userenv', 'sessionid')
```